# How can I tell that keydown will cause keypress event and in that case ignore it?

Tags: javascript, events, keyboard-events

I'm not very satisfied with the key events in javascript. I need to capture both letters for writing (I'm writing text on `<canvas>`) and functional keys (escape) for other commands.

In Firefox it works, because Firefox fires `keypress` event for *any* key. It's very comfortable but [specification directly permits it](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-keypress):

> If supported by a user agent, this event MUST be dispatched when a key is pressed down, **if and only if that key normally produces a character value**.

I disagree with that specification as I see no reason for it. But as it is now, I can't do anything about it.

Problem is that Google Chrome follows that specification and doesn't fire `keypress` for functional keys. It does, however, notmally fire `keydown` for all keys.

My program has only *one key event handler*. It expects event containing `keyCode` (the ID of the physical key and *optionally* `charCode`, the equivalent character value (for keys where it makes sense).

`keydown` event **does not contain any character values in neither browser**! It only contains the `keyCode`. So if you define a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> combination and listen for `keydown` event, your program *will be broken* for users that have QWERTZ layout - because the physical location of the key (`keyCode`) is still the same.

If you listen for both `keydown` and `keypress`, character events will fire twice (beacuse character first fires `keydown` and then `keypress` with proper `charCode` property)

#### What I need?

Based on the above, I need to ignore `keydown` event for keys that will cause `keypress`. Doing so, I'll be able to capture <kbd>Esc</kbd> in `keydown` and characters in `keypress`.

How could I possibly do it?

#### Relevant code:

```
  //Keypress for character codes
  div.addEventListener("keypress", function(event) {
    console.log(event);      
    if(_this.editor.event(event)) {
      console.log("Event canceled.");
      event.preventDefault();
      event.cancelBubble = true;
      return false;  
    }
    return true;  
  });
  //Keydown for Esc and the likes
  div.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
    //Character events are handled by keypress
    if(event.charCode!=0)  //Does NOT work - in keydown, charCode is ALLWAYS 0
      return true;    

    console.log(event);      
    if(_this.editor.event(event)) {
      console.log("Event canceled.");
      event.preventDefault();
      event.cancelBubble = true;
      return false;  
    }
    return true;
  });
```

#### [Interactive example](http://u8.8u.cz/imgedit/)

I figured I spend a lot of time making JSFiddles and it doesn't really increase the odds of getting an answer, so I instead uploaded the actual project.

Click into the white square in Firefox, press <kbd>T</kbd>, type text, press <kbd>Esc</kbd>, press <kbd>Esc</kbd>. After seconds <kbd>Esc</kbd>, cursor should get back to normal. Try to draw and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>.

Repeat the process in Google Chrome. The Escape will not work because it doesn't fire `keypress`. For some reason, the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> fires event with `keyCode` 26.

#### From chat and comments:

[@someDoge has created a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Darker/hqcLnd4w/4/) which I have expanded and which now nicely shows the situation. As you can see, you can know that a key **isn't** character and ignore it in keypress. But you can't know that <kbd>tab</kbd> isn't character and cancel it in `keydown` (unless you have fixed array of keycode values as @someDoge sugests in comments).

Comment: how about using keymaster (https://github.com/madrobby/keymaster) or keyboardjs libraries for capturing hotkeys

Comment: I'm looking for a solution and *explanation*, but thanks for mentioning these.

Comment: @someDoge You can't get actual characters reliably from keydown event (Modern browsers have `e.key`, but it's not implemented in Chrome).

Comment: @someDoge I don't know what you're talking about. Of course I **was using ctrlKey** - how else would I know it's **ctrl** +z, not just z? But if letters are mapped **diferently**, `keyDown` does **not tell you**. That's the point of whole this question...

Comment: Then use keyDown to check for the keys you need specifically and move on if it isn't them. Solved.

Comment: And how do I know which are these?

Comment: What keys do you want to implement? Due to the nature of keyboard layouts you cannot say "I want to ignore 'special keys'" without defining said special keys. If you need to use the control and escape keys, check specifically for them and if it is not them don't do anything and continue to the keypress event.

Comment: You're right, but you're not thinking enough abstract I'd say. If I want my application to be easily modifiable I definitely don't want an array of keys somewhere. Once there's a feature added to the application (in my case, every editor tool is stand alone, they can be added or removed and have key and mouse event listeners), it will be limited to keys mentioned in some array. So I want **all keys**.

Comment: When you need a list of values, you need a list of values. Your goal is to gain access to something that is not yet defined, a list of keys to watch for. No one knows what keys you're going to use. Go ahead and add them all now if you want forwards compatibility.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66051/discussion-between-tomas-zato-and-somedoge).

Answer (score 2):

You need to listen for `keyup` events instead of `keydown`, this way you won't get two separate events generated.

Then you can handle the 2 event types with the same handler function which will either get a charCode or not, depending on if the particular key generated a 'keypress' event. As long as you prevent bubbling your handler will only be called once.

Regarding the Chrome CTRL+Z problem: I don't see how you can get a charCode if the control key is being pressed, since it seems only to generate a keyup event.

Comment: Keyup event doesn't properly simulate effect we're used to: when you press a key, you expect it to take effect immediately, not after you release it.

Comment: Yes this is the only drawback. For the non-char keys, the event won't be fired until the key is released. I guess that issue will only affect Chrome and any browser that strictly implements the spec though.